# Visual Studio 2010 starts code even when current build did not succeeded - how to disable?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

At my workplace when I click ">" (Debug) button, my C# project first builds and then it runs ONLY if build was ok.

At other place, regardless of the build, last successful build runs. This is annoying.

I am having slight problems figuring out how to disable this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run

"On run, when build or deployment errors occur" has a drop down set of options. The default is "Prompt to launch", but yours is probably set to "Launch old version"

[image]